# git push heroku master errror. Failed to compile php app. could not parse composer.json

Tags: php, heroku, compiler-errors

```
-----> PHP app detected
 !     ERROR: Could not parse 'composer.json'; make sure it's valid!
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
 !     Push failed
```

my json file is just {}

Answer (score 0):

From https://getcomposer.org/schema.json, it looks like both name and description are REQUIRED. I expect you'll need to fill out at least those and then validate it before pushing.